# Calculate the number $o(\mathbb{R})$ of open subsets of the real line.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Calculate the number $o(\mathbb{R})$ of open subsets of the real line.

I know that the answer is $\mathfrak{c}$ but I don't know how my lecturer got this.

I am doing an introductory topology course, so I know a few topological concepts. Such as that the set of all open intervals forms a base for the real numbers. Is this somehow relevant in showing that  $o(\mathbb{R}) = \mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: could you use a choice function to choose a real number from each interval?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786678/prove-that-the-family-of-open-sets-in-mathbbr-has-cardinality-equal-to-2).

Answer (score 2):

There are at least $c$ of them.

Now to every open set $A$, associate the set $S_A$ of all $(s,t)$ such that $s$ and $t$ are rational and $(s,t)\subseteq A$. The set $S_A$ is completely determined by $A$. Since there are only countably many possible pairs $(s,t)$, there are at most $c$ sets $S_A$, and hence at most $c$ open sets.