# What is the cardinality of the topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, cardinals

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ equipped with usual topology $\tau$, then $\tau = 2^\mathbb{R}$

Does this imply that the cardinality of $\tau$ is greater than continuum?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786678/prove-that-the-family-of-open-sets-in-mathbbr-has-cardinality-equal-to-2

Comment: what do you mean by $\tau = 2^\mathbb R$? Not every subsets are open.