# ''Sets are not doors''

Tags: general-topology

I saw from Hunter's Analysis lecture notes, topology chapter: ''Sets are not doors. (Attributed to James Munkres.)'' What does he want to mean?

Comment: Doors are either closed or open. Sets are not.  For example $[0,1)⊂ℝ$.

Comment: @P.Siehr Thanks.

Comment: But doors could be also ajar...

Comment: Then take $∅⊂ℝ$ as an example...

Comment: Also sets are not The Doors. Although Jim Morrison was a key element in the development of modern rock music.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen As I am not a native english speaker, could you say what you mean by "ajar" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie **ajar** is what a door looks like when you meant to close it but didn't quite succeed.

Comment: @steven gregory Thanks!

Comment: Sets can also be closed *and* open at the same time: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyD4p8_y8Kw

Answer (score 4):

It means that a set can be not closed and not open as the interval $(0,1]$ ,or  closed and open as the empty set.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: However the joke relies on the topology you place on your set. Non trivial examples of clopen sets like the reals With upper limit topology.

Answer (score 2):

Hunter explains two paragraphs later:

> The empty set ∅ and R are both open and closed; they’re the only such sets. Most subsets of R are neither open nor closed (so, unlike doors, “not open” doesn’t mean “closed” and “not closed” doesn’t mean “open”)."

Comment: I've never been deep into set-theory, but isn't the amount of "closed subsets" the same as the amount  of "neither open nor closed" subsets?

Comment: @P.Siehr It turns out that there aren't very many closed subsets. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786678

Comment: Thank you for that link.

Answer (score 0):

A set is either open, closed or both or neither. (While a door is either open or closed). This depends on the topology you place on your set. For example in the reals with the standard topology as others have pointed out intervals of the form $[a,b)$ are neither while the empty set and all of the reals are closed and open. For an example of a nontrivial clopen set consider the reals with the lower limit topology. Then $[a,b)$ is clopen (both open and closed) as it’s complement is open it’s closed and it’s defined to be open in the lower limit topology. So the joke is really a joke for topologists. As open and closed and neither and clopen sets depend solely on the topology you define on your set.