# Show that $\mathcal{O}$ the set of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, cardinals

I've seen the post from here [Prove that the family of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$
has cardinality equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786678/prove-that-the-family-of-open-sets-in-mathbbr-has-cardinality-equal-to-2)

This post is somewhat complex for me, and I turned it to the question as my question suggested.

**My attempt:**

By Schröder–Bernstein theorem, it sufficient to find two injective functions $f:\mathcal{O}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{O}$ to complete the proof.

The open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is uniquely determined by its endpoint $(a,b)$, where $a<b$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Each real numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ can split into **integer part** $a_1$ and **decimal part** $0.a_2a_3a_4\ldots$ such that

$$
a=a_1.a_2a_3a_4\ldots\\
b=b_1.b_2b_3b_4\ldots
$$

Define

\begin{align} 
&f:\mathcal{O}\to\mathbb{R}\\
&(a,b)\to a_1b_1.b_2a_2a_3b_3b_4a_4\dots
\end{align}

$a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ must differ in at least one digit and the "function routine" is fixed, hence it must be injective.

Define
\begin{align} 
g:&\mathbb{R}\to \mathcal{O}\\
&x\to (x,x+1)
\end{align}

This easily can seen as injective, hence $\mathcal{O}\sim\mathbb{R}$

**Please leave some comments to tell me if this proof either correct or not**

Comment: Open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are not just intervals!

Comment: @user14111 Like what else of "lots of work"?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I think if I push further to show all the open sets and all the open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are equinumerous can complete the proof. Injectivity from all open intervals to all open sets by identity function, the other way I might need to take some time.

Comment: @user14111 I can see that each open set contains a certain number of open rational endpoint intervals, and we map the number to the real through $\sum_{I_n\subset U}3^{-n}$. but I don't see how it would be injective, what if two distinct open sets contain the same number of rational endpoint open interval.

Comment: @user14111 Thank you for your reply. your reasoning looks good to me but I am still unsure about this conclusion $\{n:I_n\subseteq U\}\neq\{n:I_n\subseteq V\}$. Lets say $U=(1,2)\cup (3,4)$ and $V=(5,6)\cup (7,8)$. Put it another way, how many $I_n$ satisfy $I_n\subseteq U$ and  $I_n\subseteq V$, respectively? Do they both have countably infinite $I_n$, but with different $n$?

Comment: @user14111 I am still confused on this result. To be more specific, the non-empty open set contains (I think) countably infinity rational intervals, then both should equals to $\aleph_0$, then how could they have different $n$ such that $\{n:I_n\subseteq U\}\neq \{n:I_n\subseteq V\}$